# DigestAuthenticationFilter and PasswordEncoder in Spring Security 5

Tags: spring-security, password-encryption, digest-authentication

Based on [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#digest-config):

> The configured UserDetailsService is needed because DigestAuthenticationFilter must have direct access to the clear text password of a user. Digest Authentication will NOT work if you are using encoded passwords in your DAO

So this means that `DigestAuthenticationFilter` forces us to use `NoOpPasswordEncoder` which is deprecated in spring security 5.

Is there another way to configure digest authentication and avoid using deprecated encoder? Or I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It is stated as a foot note:

It is possible to encode the password in the format HEX( MD5(username:realm:password) ) provided the DigestAuthenticationFilter.passwordAlreadyEncoded is set to true. However, other password encodings will not work with digest authentication.